Movie with two orphan boys
I saw a movie about late 70s, when I was a child. It was about two orphans, a black and a white boy. They became very close friends and one night, I don't remember why, they were out and it was very cold and it was snowing, I think and the black boy protected his friend and in the morning, he was dead.
Please, help me if you know the title of the movie.

please provide details like approximate year, country\language, where you saw it, possible actors etc. It'll help the question get more positive response

I think you are describing Forever Young, Forever Free, (1975).  
From Amazon:

Forever Young, Forever Free is a studied piece of whimsy filmed in
  South Africa and Harlem. Norman Knox plays a white orphan installed in
  a South African mission; his best friend is black foundling Muntu Ben
  Louis Ndebele. When Norman requires emergency surgery, he is flown to
  New York, where he bemoans the fact that he has been separated from
  his black chum. Whereupon, Muntu and priest Jose Fesser jet to the big
  apple themselves--but Muntu gets lost in the airport, and winds up in
  Harlem

I remember the ending you describe, except that when the searchers pull them from the snow, one of them says the boys are alive.  It could easily have been an alternate ending.  An extended trailer is on Youtube.  There is a brief glimpse of the scene in the snow at about 4:29.

Will Feldman, thank you so much. This is the movie! I saw the trailer and i remembered when they played with the wheel. I think that's when they discovered that  Norman is sick. Then I saw Muntu in New York and I remembered that his clothes were made of a blanket.... My God, it's been so long but I remembered so many things... I discovered on Daily Motion the whole movie and I watched the final scene... Well, as I said... he died.... I was little and when I saw that he was dead, I hid under the bed and I cried, and cried.... Thank you so much!!!!

@athena If this is the correct answer, please approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it.
